# Incompatible types when assigning to type 'char*[length] ' from type 'char*' (matrix + structure)

Tags: c

I'm doing my homework. We have to make matrix with new type struct.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef char* String;
typedef struct{
  String Name[10];
  String ID[6];
  float yo;
}data;

int main(){
  data user[3][3];
  // some code
  // wanna assign value
  user[0][0].Name="Charles";
  user[0][0].ID="123123";
  user[0][0].yo=20;
  // another code
}
```

When I try to compile it, it shows errors

> [Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'char*[10]' from type'char*'

How to fix it?

Comment: You can't assign like that. Use `strcpy`.

Comment: Also, your declaration should probably be `String Name;` else you have an array of pointers and not an array of chars.

Comment: @Tiara in my answer you ha 3 ways of "fixing" it

Comment: Just never hide pointers behind a typedef. And never take the CS50 class...

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: `String Name;` results in `Name` being a **pointer to** `char`, a `char*` and  "*not an array of chars*".

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i wrote `String Name;` and it solves my problem. thankyou

Answer (score 3):

I think your typedef is not helping you understanding the problem.

```
typedef char* String;
String Name[10];
```

Here you wrote `String Name[10]` Which is an equivalent to `char *Name[10]` which is and array of pointer on char.

```
user[0][0].Name="Charles";
```

Here you are assiging the value `Charles` (which can be understanded as a char*) to a variable of type `char *[]`

Moreover if you want to assign a `char *` value (assuming that you solved the first problem), you may use `strcpy` or `strdup` for example, (if you use `strcpy` don't forget to `malloc`)

Hope you understand

Comment: Yes, but `strcpy` will not solve this particular problem either.  For its part, although `strdup` might be appropriate here, it does not produce a result that is any more assignable to `user[0][0].Name` than is a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

As @KillianG. already answered, it looks like you may have muddied the issue for yourself by defining and using the `String` type.  In general, it tends to be more harmful than helpful to define types that disguise pointer nature, as that one does.

I think the deepest problem here is that you have defined your data structure differently than you meant to do.  Given the type

> ```
> typedef char* String;
> ```

You might write code like this ...

```
String a_name = "Alice";
```

... but your structure is not analogous:

> ```
> typedef struct{
>   String Name[10];
>   String ID[6];
>   float yo;
> }data;
> ```

You have defined the `Name` member to be an array *of `String`s*, so ten pointers, whereas it seems likely that you instead want an array of `char`, suitable for holding one C string:

```
typedef struct {
  char Name[10];
  char ID[6];
  float yo;
} data;
```

Alternatively, perhaps you want `Name` to be a single string, in which case you should declare it that way:

```
  String Name;
  // equivalent to: char *Name;
```

There is no need or capability to set a maximum string length in the latter case, because such a thing is not an attribute of a `char *`; the length of a C string is a function of the character data, not of the array containing them.

Let's supposing you go with the first alternative,

```
  char Name[10];
```

Now you have to handle the fact that C does not provide an operator for whole-array copying.  In particular, the left-hand operand of an `=` operator cannot be a whole array.  Instead, you can populate arrays element-by-element, or via various functions that have that effect (`memcpy`, `memmove`).  There is a subfamily of such functions specific to copying string data: `strcpy`, `strncpy`, *etc*..  Given that the string (*not `String`!*) `"Charles"` is known to require only 8 chars, including its terminator, the idiomatic way to copy that data into an existing `data` object's `Name` member would be via `strcpy()`:

```
data user[3][3];

// This:
strcpy(user[0][0], "Charles");
```

Answer (score -2):

You cant do it this way as your `NAME` and `ID` are tables of pointers to char

```
int main(){
  data user[3][3];
  // some code
  // wanna assign value
  user[0][0].Name[0]="Charles";
  user[0][0].ID[0]="123123";
  user[0][0].yo=20;
  // another code
}
```

or

```
typedef char* String;
typedef struct{
  String Name;
  String ID;
  float yo;
}data;

int main(){
  data user[3][3];
  // some code
  // wanna assign value
  user[0][0].Name="Charles";
  user[0][0].ID="123123";
  user[0][0].yo=20;
  // another code
}
```

or

```
typedef char* String;
typedef struct{
  char Name[10];
  char ID[7];
  float yo;
}data;

int main(){
  data user[3][3];
  // some code
  // wanna assign value
  strcpy(user[0][0].Name,"Charles");
  strcpy(user[0][0].ID,"123123");
  user[0][0].yo=20;
  // another code
}
```